# Issues with continuing U-Net training after interruption in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm using Google Colab to train a U-Net network for object detection (a single object). My issue is that many times, the training is interrupted for various reasons, forcing me to restart the process. I'm using the following code to try to continue training from where I left off, but every time I try, the algorithm starts training from epoch 1 again. For example, if I trained for 30 epochs, it should continue from epoch 31 onwards, but instead, the algorithm starts from the first epoch, which indicates that the training is not continuing but rather starting anew.

Here is the particular section where I'm attempting to resume training from where I left off:

```
import os
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

# Caminho para o diretório de checkpoints (o mesmo usado durante o treinamento)
checkpoint_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/checkpoints/'

# Carregue o modelo (certifique-se de que a arquitetura é a mesma)
model = unet()

# Defina o otimizador e compile o modelo (use os mesmos parâmetros do treinamento original)
optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Carregue os pesos do modelo a partir do último checkpoint
model.load_weights(os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'best_checkpoint.ckpt'))

# ModelCheckpoint para salvar os melhores checkpoints
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'best_checkpoint.ckpt'),
    save_weights_only=True,  # Salvar apenas os pesos do modelo
    save_best_only=True,  # Salvar apenas o melhor checkpoint com base na métrica de validação
    monitor='val_loss',  # Métrica de validação a ser monitorada (ajuste conforme necessário)
    verbose=1
)

# EarlyStopping para interromper o treinamento se não houver melhora na métrica de validação
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    patience=10,  # Número de épocas sem melhora para interromper o treinamento
    restore_best_weights=True,  # Restaurar os melhores pesos do modelo
    verbose=1
)

# Continue o treinamento a partir da última época
history = model.fit(
    np.array(train_images),
    np.array(train_masks),
    epochs=500,  # Ajuste conforme necessário
    batch_size=6,  # Ajuste conforme necessário
    validation_data=(np.array(test_images), np.array(test_masks)),
    callbacks=[model_checkpoint, early_stopping]
)
```

It's important to note that the algorithm generates three files with the default training using checkpoints: best_checkpoint.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001, best_checkpoint.ckpt.index, and checkpoint.

Here's my entire code for those who want to see it:

import block

```
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Concatenate
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, average_precision_score
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

Division between train and test (csv)

```
# Caminhos para os diretórios de treinamento e teste
train_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/train/images/'
test_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/val/images/'

# Carregando o CSV geral
csv_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/nodules.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

# Criando os DataFrames para treinamento e teste
train_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=data.columns)
test_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=data.columns)

# Iterando sobre as imagens no diretório de treinamento
for img_name in os.listdir(train_dir):
    if img_name.endswith('.png'):
        img_name = img_name.strip()  # Remover espaços em branco extras, se houver
        # Procurar pela imagem correspondente no CSV geral
        rows = data[data['img_name'] == img_name]
        if not rows.empty:
            # Adicionar as linhas correspondentes ao DataFrame de treinamento
            train_data = pd.concat([train_data, rows])

# Iterando sobre as imagens no diretório de teste
for img_name in os.listdir(test_dir):
    if img_name.endswith('.png'):
        img_name = img_name.strip()  # Remover espaços em branco extras, se houver
        # Procurar pela imagem correspondente no CSV geral
        rows = data[data['img_name'] == img_name]
        if not rows.empty:
            # Adicionar as linhas correspondentes ao DataFrame de teste
            test_data = pd.concat([test_data, rows])

# Salvar os DataFrames em arquivos CSV separados
train_data.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/train_data.csv', index=False)
test_data.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/test_data.csv', index=False)
```

Loading the images and their masks

```
# Carregar os CSVs de anotações para treinamento e teste
train_annotations = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/train_data.csv')
test_annotations = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/test_data.csv')

# Diretórios das imagens de treinamento e teste
train_image_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/train/images/'
test_image_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/val/images/'

# Inicializar as máscaras e as listas de imagens
image_shape = (640, 640)
train_masks = np.zeros((len(train_annotations),) + image_shape, dtype=np.uint8)
test_masks = np.zeros((len(test_annotations),) + image_shape, dtype=np.uint8)

# Carregar as imagens de treinamento e suas máscaras
train_images = []
for img_name in train_annotations['img_name']:
    img = cv2.imread(train_image_dir + img_name, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    train_images.append(img)

    # Itere sobre as anotações e crie as máscaras de treinamento
    for i, row in train_annotations.iterrows():
        x, y, width, height = row['x'], row['y'], row['width'], row['height']
        train_masks[i, y:y+height, x:x+width] = 1

# Carregar as imagens de teste e suas máscaras
test_images = []
for img_name in test_annotations['img_name']:
    img = cv2.imread(test_image_dir + img_name, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    test_images.append(img)

    # Iterar sobre as anotações e crie as máscaras de teste
    for i, row in test_annotations.iterrows():
        x, y, width, height = row['x'], row['y'], row['width'], row['height']
        test_masks[i, y:y+height, x:x+width] = 1

# Dividir os dados em conjuntos de treinamento e teste
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_images, train_masks, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

The model

```
# Função para construir a U-Net
def unet(input_shape=(640, 640, 1)):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)

    # Parte de codificação (downsampling)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    (...)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    # Parte de decodificação (upsampling)
    up6 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5)
    up6 = Concatenate()([up6, conv4])
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

    (...)

    up9 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8)
    up9 = Concatenate()([up9, conv1])
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    # Saída
    outputs = Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

model = unet()

# Compilação do modelo
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Visualização da arquitetura da U-Net
model.summary()
```

The training script

```
# Caminho para o diretório onde deseja salvar os checkpoints
checkpoint_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/YOLOv8/tentativa_1/checkpoints/'

# Certifique-se de que o diretório de checkpoints exista, caso contrário, crie-o
os.makedirs(checkpoint_dir, exist_ok=True)

# ModelCheckpoint para salvar apenas os melhores checkpoints
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'best_checkpoint.ckpt'),
    save_weights_only=True,  # Salvar apenas os pesos do modelo
    save_best_only=True,  # Salvar apenas o melhor checkpoint com base na métrica de validação
    monitor='val_loss',  # Métrica de validação a ser monitorada (pode ser ajustada)
    verbose=1
)

# EarlyStopping para interromper o treinamento se não houver melhora na métrica de validação
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    patience=10,  # Número de épocas sem melhora para interromper o treinamento
    restore_best_weights=True,  # Restaurar os melhores pesos do modelo
    verbose=1
)

# Continue o treinamento a partir da última época
history = model.fit(
    np.array(train_images),
    np.array(train_masks),
    epochs=100,
    batch_size=4,
    validation_data=(np.array(test_images), np.array(test_masks)),
    callbacks=[model_checkpoint, early_stopping]
)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Mostly unreproducible, because we lack your dataset. However, have you seen the training metrics after resuming? Do they continue from they left or they start anew? If you do not set the `initial_epoch` parameter in `fit()`, you will start counting from epoch `0` again, but this should not affect the last saved state of the model. Lastly, the optimizer state does not get saved with `save_weights_only`.

Comment: You literally saved me. This solved the issue, thank you so much! Wish you the best @stateMachine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @stateMachine, we need to use initial_epoch in the fit() parameter. When it comes to my code, i needed to use save_weights_only = true, to save the optimizer state.

Thank you @stateMachine for the reply in the comment.